# Enable local Internet when connected to Azure VPN via VPN Client

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

I have an Azure (Classic) VNet with Point-to-Site enabled.  I went through uploading a certificate and downloading the VPN Client.  When I connect to the VPN, I am able to access all my resources fine, but this disables my local Internet access.

I found and went through this article which seemed applicable (if very cumbersome): http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2013/11/27/deconstructing-the-azure-point-to-site-vpn-for-command-line-usage

I am unable to connect using the custom connection I created with it as it tells me the certificate is incorrect (though the .pbk it is based off works fine).

I suppose I could jump through some hoops to get internet to pipe through the VPN, but I really don't want that.  I need to be able to hit the VMs in my VNet from an application that I am running locally, and I want to be able to pull the CDNs in over my local internet connection.

This shouldn't be this hard, should it?

Thanks,
~john

Answer (score 0):

Have you ensured that the VPN address range you have defined in Vnet doesn't overlap with your LAN IP ranges? Say if your local workstation has private IP range in 192.168.x.x range, you can try setting VPN address range in 172.16.x.x range.